# Need concrete documentation / examples of building complex index using NEST ElasticSearch library

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to use the NEST library's Fluent interface to create an index, which involves setting up custom filters, analyzers, and type mappings.  I would like to avoid decorating my classes with NEST-specific annotations.

I have seen the documentation at http://nest.azurewebsites.net/indices/create-indices.html and  http://nest.azurewebsites.net/indices/put-mapping.html.  This documentation, while showing some examples, is not complete enough to help me figure out how to use the Fluent API to build some complex indexing scenarios.

I have found the tutorial at http://euphonious-intuition.com/2012/08/more-complicated-mapping-in-elasticsearch/ to be quite helpful; some code showing how to build the filters, analyzers and mappings in this tutorial via the NEST Fluent interface in place of the straight JSON would be a great answer to this question.

Comment: Holy crap yes, it would be nice to have better documentation on Nest. Awesome tool, but hard to find the details beyond the basics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more specific you can be with your question the better the answers you receive will be. Nevertheless, here is an index that sets up an analyzer (with filter) and tokenizer (EdgeNGram) and then uses them to create an autocomplete index on the Name field of a Tag class.

```cs
public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Nest.IElasticClient client = null; // Connect to ElasticSearch

var createResult = client.CreateIndex(indexName, index => index
    .Analysis(analysis => analysis
        .Analyzers(a => a
            .Add(
                "autocomplete",
                new Nest.CustomAnalyzer()
                {
                    Tokenizer = "edgeNGram",
                    Filter = new string[] { "lowercase" }
                }
            )
        )
        .Tokenizers(t => t
            .Add(
                "edgeNGram",
                new Nest.EdgeNGramTokenizer()
                {
                    MinGram = 1,
                    MaxGram = 20
                }
            )
        )
    )
    .AddMapping<Tag>(tmd => tmd
        .Properties(props => props
            .MultiField(p => p
                .Name(t => t.Name)
                .Fields(tf => tf
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(t => t.Name)
                        .Index(Nest.FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)
                    )
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(t => t.Name.Suffix("autocomplete"))
                        .Index(Nest.FieldIndexOption.analyzed)
                        .IndexAnalyzer("autocomplete")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

There is also a fairly complete mapping example in NEST's unit test project on github.
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs

**Edit:**

To query the index, do something like the following:

```cs
string queryString = ""; // search string
var results = client.Search<Tag>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Text(tq => tq
            .OnField(t => t.Name.Suffix("autocomplete"))
            .QueryString(queryString)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful

Comment: @Joe Waller: what would be the search query for this. I'm able to create the above index, but not able to get the auto-complete working.

Comment: @gsk: I have updated my answer with an example query.

Comment: @JoeWaller: Thank you very much for that update. But I'm not able to get it to work, receiving 0 hits. I have indexed the same way as you mentioned and queried the same way. How should I ensure that the edgeNgram tokenizer has been applied (or analyzed)? The text in my property (which is indexed in elastic search ) is "Test", but when I search "tes" or "test", it is yielding 0 hits.

Comment: @gsk: That's odd. This is pretty much exactly what I use with much success in my own application. You should open up another SO question detailing your problem.

Comment: All of this is good, but where can i find examples about refresh/update/reindex functions? Search - it's quite easy, but serious systems need periodically refresh of data.

Comment: @MaksimPavlov: http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/ - If you have a specific question ask it here on Stackoverflow and I'm sure someone can help you out (might even be me :))