# Nest SuggestCompletion usage, throws 'is not a completion suggest field' exception

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm a complete beginner to elasticsearch and I have been trying to use elasticsearch's completion suggester using Nest for auto-complete on a property.

Here is my mapping (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs): ):

```
var createResult = client.CreateIndex(indexName, index => index                
            .AddMapping<Contact>(tmd => tmd
                .Properties(props => props
                    .Completion(s =>
                        s.Name(p => p.CompanyName.Suffix("completion"))
                        .IndexAnalyzer("standard")
                        .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                        .MaxInputLength(20)
                        .Payloads()
                        .PreservePositionIncrements()
                        .PreserveSeparators())                        
                )
            )
        );

var resultPerson = client.IndexMany(documents.OfType<Person>(), new SimpleBulkParameters { Refresh = true });
var resultCompany = client.IndexMany(documents.OfType<Company>(), new SimpleBulkParameters { Refresh = true });
```

And while indexing I'm just making use of `IndexMany` method and passing the `IEnumerable<Contact>` (Contact has a property by name CompanyName, Contact is an abstract class, both Person and Company are concrete implementations of it). The search throws an exception saying

> ElasticSearchException[Field [companyName] is not a completion suggest field]

And the query looks like below:

```
SearchDescriptor<Contact> descriptor = new SearchDescriptor<Contact>();
descriptor = descriptor.SuggestCompletion("suggest", c => c.OnField(f => f.CompanyName).Text(q));

var result = getElasticClientInstance("contacts").Search<Contact>(body => descriptor);

string qe = result.ConnectionStatus.ToString();
```

What am I doing wrong here, I looked into Nest's tests on `SuggestCompletion` but not much help, meaning the test only depict on how to get suggestions but not on how to set index mappings for SuggestCompletion.

I also tried setting up `edgeNgram` tokenizer as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519449/need-concrete-documentation-examples-of-building-complex-index-using-nest-elas) but, couldn't proceed there as well.

Any direction  or an example on how to proceed would greatly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You are try to create a property with the name "companyName.completion" but at that position its not valid and it will use the last token "completion". So its actually mapping a field called completion.... try changing the call to: `.Name(p => p.CompanyName)`

**Other observations**

You specify a mapping for the `Contact` but while indexing you use the `Person` and `Company` types.

In elasticsearch terms you mapped:

`/index/contact/`

but your documents are going into:

`/index/person/` and `/index/company`

NEST won't automatically map all implementation of a specific class and elasticsearch has no way of knowing the three are related.

I would refactor the mapping to a method and call it for all the types involved.

```
 var createResult = client.CreateIndex(indexName, index => index                
      .AddMapping<Contact>(tmd => MapContactCompletionFields(tmd))
      .AddMapping<Person>(tmd => MapContactCompletionFields(tmd))
      .AddMapping<Company>(tmd => MapContactCompletionFields(tmd))   
  );

 private RootObjectMappingDescriptor<TContact>  MapContactCompletionFields<TContact>(
      RootObjectMappingDescriptor<TContact> tmd)
      where TContact : Contact
 {
      return  tmd.Properties(props => props
           .Completion(s => s
                .Name(p => p.CompanyName.Suffix("completion"))
                .IndexAnalyzer("standard")
                .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                .MaxInputLength(20)
                .Payloads()
                .PreservePositionIncrements()
                .PreserveSeparators()
           )                        
       );
 }
```

That method returns the descriptor so you can further chain on it.

Then when you do a search for contacts:

```
var result = getElasticClientInstance("contacts").Search<Contact>(
    body => descriptor
        .Types(typeof(Person), typeof(Company))
);
```

That types hint will cause the search to looking `/index/person` and `/index/company` and will know how to give you back a covariant list of documents.

So you can do `result.Documents.OfType<Person>()` after the previous call.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I still get the same issue: **ElasticSearchException[Field [companyName] is not a completion suggest field]**. Here is my query: `StatusCode: InternalServerError, 
 Method: POST, 
 Url: http://192.168.1.105:9200/contacts/people/_search, 
 Request: {
  "suggest": {
    "suggest": {
      "text": "land",
      "completion": {
        "field": "companyName"
      }
    }
  }
}`. and I'm not sure how "Person" is being taken as "People", no where I'm mentioning that. Same for Company, it shows up as Companies, and contact as contacts. Are two 'suggests' in the query ok?.

Comment: Can you paste the response for  http://192.168.1.105:9200/contacts/_mapping in your answer? or as a gist on github ?

Comment: ahhh i get what is happening, you are try to create a property with the name "companyName.completion" but at that position its not valid and it will use the last token "completion". So its actually mapping a field called `completion`.... try changing the call to: `.Name(p => p.CompanyName)`

Comment: Wow, that did the trick, thank you. Now, the result is showing total hits as all objects, should it pull only those that have this text?. And the output has suggests based on my query, I'm not sure how to pull the suggests to show to user, I'm assuming I need to query the suggests dictionary. https://gist.github.com/BharathChandra/8708544

Comment: Yeah NEST currently only supports suggests on the `_search` endpoint so set a `.Size(0)` on the search descriptor `_suggest` endpoint support is in the works!. Can you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: @MartijnLaarman can you help me out? I'm stuck on a similar situation here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717387/suggestcompletion-nest-usage