# SuggestCompletion Nest usage

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to do a SuggestCompletion query for a location (countries and cities), I'd like to perform the query over those two fields.

my mapping so far is the following:

```
var response =  _client.CreateIndex(PlatformConfiguration.LocationIndexName,
                    descriptor => descriptor.AddMapping<LocationInfo>(
                        m => m.Properties(
                            p => p.Completion(s => s
                                .Name(n=>n.CountryName)
                                .IndexAnalyzer("simple")
                                .SearchAnalyzer("simple")
                                .MaxInputLength(50)
                                .Payloads()
                                .PreserveSeparators()
                                .PreservePositionIncrements()).
                                Completion(s=>s.Name(n => n.City)
                                .IndexAnalyzer("simple")
                                .SearchAnalyzer("simple")
                                .MaxInputLength(50)
                                .Payloads()
                                .PreserveSeparators()
                                .PreservePositionIncrements())
                            )));
```

**Edit:**
How I'm indexing the elements:

```
public bool IndexLocations(IList<LocationInfo> locations)

        {
            var bulkParams = locations.Select(p => new BulkParameters<LocationInfo>(p){
                Id = p.Id, 
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToTimeStamp()
            });
            var response = _client.IndexMany(bulkParams, PlatformConfiguration.LocationIndexName);
            return response.IsValid;
        }
```

**Edit**

After viewing the mappings I changed my query to the following:

```
var response = _client.Search<LocationInfo>(location =>
                location.Index(PlatformConfiguration.LocationIndexName).
                    SuggestCompletion("locationinfo", f => f.OnField("countryName").Text(text).Size(1)));
```

and I also I tried:

```
 var response = _client.Search<LocationInfo>(location =>
                location.Index(PlatformConfiguration.LocationIndexName).
                    SuggestCompletion("countryName", f => f.OnField("countryName").Text(text).Size(1)));
```

.....And I still get an empty result

**the mapping**

```
{
  "locationindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "locationinfo": {
        "properties": {
          "countryName": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "payloads": true,
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
          }
        }
      },
      "bulkparameters`1": {
        "properties": {
          "document": {
            "properties": {
              "city": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "countryName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "countryTwoDigitCode": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "latitude": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "longitude": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "versionType": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking at the Suggest property that is returned with the response?  Keep in mind that the completion suggester will not return you documents, it will only return text suggestions and an optional payload object, which you specify at index time.

Comment: @GregMarzouka take a look to the update, it seems like I'm not getting any suggestion

Comment: Your NEST mapping setup looks correct but would you mind posting your actual mapping (GET /index/_mapping) and the document that contains the country name that "boca" should suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for `IndexMany()` with wrapped `BulkParameters` has been removed in `NEST 1.0.0 beta 1`

If you want to use a bulk with more advanced parameters you now have to use the `Bulk()` command.

The beta sadly still shipped with the `BulkParameters` class [in the assembly](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/1.0.0-beta1/src/Nest/Domain/Parameters/BulkParameters.cs)

This has since been removed in the develop branch.

So what happens now is that you are actually indexing ``` "bulkparameters``1``" ``` type documents and not `"locationinfo"`. So the mapping specified for `"locationinfo"` does not come into play.

See [here for an example](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Integration/Core/Bulk/BulkTests.cs#L134-L138) on how to use `Bulk()` to index many objects at once while configuring advanced parameters for individual items.