# ElasticSearch Nest AutoComplete based on words split by whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have AutoComplete working with ElasticSearch (Nest) and it's fine when the user types in the letters from the begining of the phrase but I would like to be able to use a specialized type of auto complete if it's possible that caters for words in a sentence.

To clarify further, my requirement is to be able to "auto complete" like such:

> Imagine the full indexed string is **"this is some title"**. When the user types in **"th"**, this comes back as a suggestion with my current code.
>
> I would also like the same thing to be returned if the user types in **"som"** or **"title"** or any letters that form a word (word being classified as a string between two spaces or the start/end of the string).

The code I have is:

```
var result = _client.Search<ContentIndexable>(
            body => body
                        .Index(indexName)
                        .SuggestCompletion("content-suggest" + Guid.NewGuid(),
                                           descriptor =>
                                           descriptor
                                               .OnField(t => t.Title.Suffix("completion"))
                                               .Text(searchTerm)
                                               .Size(size)));
```

And I would like to see if it would be possible to write something that matches my requirement using `SuggestCompletion` (and not by doing a match query).

Many thanks,

**Update:**
This question already has an answer here but I leave it here since the title/description is probably a little easier to search by search engines.

The correct solution to this problem can be found here:
[Elasticsearch NEST client creating multi-field fields with completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285065/elasticsearch-nest-client-creating-multi-field-fields-with-completion/30285724#30285724)

Answer (score 0):

@Kha i think it's better to use the [NGram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

So you should use this tokenizer when you create the mapping.
If you want more info, and maybe an example write back.